# Passing Kendo Grid selected item into Kendo Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have got a Kendo Grid with editable records:

[image]

When the user clicks the edit button, a Kendo Window opens with a form to edit the record.

[image]

I am achieving this by filling the Kendo Window from a controller method that fetches the data of the selected record via webservice: **<- this is what I want to avoid**. Instead, I want to take the data straight out from the table and put it into the input fields inside the Kendo Window, without any additional processing or html calls. The data is already on the table, I just don't know how to send it to the Kendo Window inputs.

Here's some code:

The javascript function called after clicking the edit button:

```
function openEdit() {
    var window = $("#editWindow").getKendoWindow();
    window.refresh({
        url: '@Url.Action("_EditForm", "Controller")'
    });
    window.center().open();
}
```

The view contains a partial view call:

```
@Html.Partial("_EditWindow")
```

The called partial view contains the Kendo Window:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("editWindow")
    .Modal(true)
    .Events(e => e.Open("drawWindow").Close("refresh").Refresh("hideLoading"))
    .Iframe(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Title("Edit Record")
)
```

How can the data from the selected row of the table be passed to the Kendo Window?

### EDIT

I know how to get the values from the selected record in javascript:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
```

I just don't know how to pass them into the Kendo Window inputs.

Comment: There is a very detailed Tutorial here: [Kendo Grid - Popup Editing](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-popup)

Comment: @Bubavanhalen, thank you for your answer. However, I have seen that and that's not what I am looking for. I want a customized window and buttons, not present there.

Comment: Oh.. Im Sorry.. For this case you can use an editor template. [Example](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/361804_popup-template-example.zip?sfvrsn=0). And here the  [Description](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-popup-editor-with-additional-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to a solution for my problem. I now send the selected model from the view to the controller. I use the fantastic `JSON.stringify` to achieve it.

```
function onChange() {
    if (this.dataItem(this.select()) != null) {
        var rowModel = this.dataItem(this.select());
        // gets the model of the selected item in the grid

        $.ajax({
            url: 'sendGridRecord',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(rowModel),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a partial view as per the requirement and render that on a kendow window on edit button click.i.e

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("myWindow")
      .Content(Html.Partial(@Url.Content("~/Views/_EditWindow.cshtml")).ToString())
      .Visible(false).Title("XYZ").Modal(true).Actions(actions => actions
          .Custom("custom")
          .Minimize()
          .Maximize()
          .Close()
      ).Resizable().Draggable())


function openEdit() {
//Open the kendow window here.
//Get the seleceted item
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
//populate the partial view fields using the selectedItem variable like
$('#name').val(selectedItem.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two methods in order to pass the Kendo().Grid()'s selected row data:

**Method I:**

```
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(@<text>
            <div class="toolbar">
                @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("myBtn")                        
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary k-button k-button-icontext", onclick = "callActionBySelectedRowId('#GridMaster')" })  
                    .Content("Add New")
                )
            </div>
        </text>);
    })

function callActionBySelectedRowId(grid) {
    var grid = $(grid).data('kendoGrid');
    id = grid.dataItem(grid.select()).ID;
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")/' + id;       
}
```

**Method II:**

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoMVCWrappers.Models.Person>().Name("persons")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(m => m.PersonID);

                })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetPersons", "Home"))
            .Update(up => up.Action("UpdatePerson", "Home"))
    )
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.BirthDate);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
)

<input type="button" id="btn" name="name" value="send to Server!" />




<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $('#btn').click(function () {
           var items = {};
           var grid = $('#persons').data('kendoGrid');
           var selectedElements = grid.select();

           for (var j = 0; j < selectedElements.length; j++) {
               var item = grid.dataItem(selectedElements[j]);
               items['persons[' + j + '].Name'] = item.Name;
                items['persons[' + j + '].PersonID'] = item.PersonID;
           }

           //If you want to pass single item parameter use this and comment out "for loop" & use the second "data" line below:
           //var singleItem = grid.dataItem(selectedElements[0]);

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               data: items,
               //data: { ID: singleItem.ID }, //for passing single item parameter 
               url: '@Url.Action("Test","Home")',
               success: function (result) {
                   console.log(result);
               }
           })
       })
   })
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Test(Person[] persons)
{
    return Json(persons);
}
```

**Note:** If the View called from Controller cannot be rendered use the javascript function as below by using window.location.href instead of $.ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            var items = {};
            var grid = $('#persons').data('kendoGrid');
            var selectedElements = grid.select();
            var item = grid.dataItem(selectedElements[0]);

            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")/' + item.ID;             
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already managed to find a solution to my issue, I will post it

Comment: I am happy that you had solved the problem :) I also hope this solution and the other way you use will help the others who encounter this problem in the future. So, it would be nice if you post your solution so that others can benefit from it. Thanks...

Comment: If you wish I can improve my answer by explaining what is done in the controller to send the data to the Kendo Window

Comment: Actually I used this approach before the solution I posted above, but it did not worked for me. I tried to many different ways, but nothing changed. So, using ajax failed for some reason. Anyway, if you post the detailed info, I will try it on the next time (I think it would be better to use ajax). Thanks again.