# Getting id of selected node in a Kendo TreeView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I've got this controller method that sends the tree items to the tree in the view:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> GetTrees()
{
    InstallationPlaceModel ipm = new InstallationPlaceModel();
    var gipo = ipm.getRootInstallationPlaces();
    List<TreeViewItemModel> fullTree = new List<TreeViewItemModel>();

    foreach (wsInstallationPlace.installationPlaceOutput father in gipo.installationPlaces)
    {
        var gipo2 = ipm.getChildInstallationPlaces(father.installationPlace.id);
        List<TreeViewItemModel> childTree = new List<TreeViewItemModel>();

        foreach (wsInstallationPlace.installationPlaceOutput child in gipo2.installationPlaces)
        {
            TreeViewItemModel childTreeItem = new TreeViewItemModel
            {
                Text = child.installationPlace.mediumDescription,
                Id = child.installationPlace.id
            };          
            childTree.Add(childTreeItem);
        }
        TreeViewItemModel fatherTreeItem = new TreeViewItemModel
        {
            Text = father.installationPlace.mediumDescription,
            Id = father.installationPlace.id,
            Items = childTree
        };
        fullTree.Add(fatherTreeItem);
    }
    ViewBag.mytree = fullTree;
    return fullTree;
}
```

This is the Kendo TreeView:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .DragAndDrop(true)
    .Events(e => e.Select("onSelect"))
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)ViewBag.mytree)
)
```

And this function to handle selection of a tree node:

```
function onSelect(e) {
    alert(this.text(e.node));
}
```

When a node is selected, an alert with the node's text is displayed. I wanted to show the id of the node. I tried:

```
function onSelect(e) {
    alert(this.id(e.node));
}
```

but no luck. As you can see in the controller method, I am filling the `text` and `id` properties but I can only access the text. Any help?

**## LIVE DEMO**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the `id` of the selected node, you should use `$(e.node).data("id")`.

```
function onSelect(e) {
    alert($(e.node).data("id"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you OnaBai, it works. I'm amazed as the solutions are not intuitive at all, do you know where can I find documentation to guide me on Kendo? Documentation is essential and I can't see any helpful one. Also, I see you are a kind of Kendo expert, could you please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929767/passing-kendo-grid-selected-item-into-kendo-window) and help me? Again, thank you. +1 and correct answer